# Using bound methods in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have an object called `my_object`. I want to create 3 different instances of `my_object` and run a bound method `my_object.test()`, with each instance of the object method being run in a different process. The `my_object` constructor creates and starts a thread, and `test()` is supposed to send a message to the thread over a queue. The thread then prints the message. `my_object` looks like this:

```
class my_object():
    class my_thread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, message_queue):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.message_queue = message_queue
        def run(self):
            while not self.message_queue.empty():
                try:
                    message = self.message_queue.get_nowait()
                    print message
                except Queue.Empty:
                    time.sleep(0.1)

    def __init__(self):
        self.message_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.mythread = my_object.my_thread(self.message_queue)
        self.mythread.start()

    def test(self):
        print "Sending message"
        message = "test"
        self.message_queue.put(message)
```

When I start a process like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = my_object()
    p = Process(target=obj.test)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

`test()` will execute the print command, but the thread never receives the message put on `message_queue.` When I start a process like this:

```
def test():
   obj = my_object()
   obj.test() 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=test)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

My code works as expected.

(Note my `main` method and `my_object` code are in separate files)

I've read that you can't pickle bound methods, but I thought that only applies to `multiprocess.Pool` not to mention it appears that `obj.test()` is being executed, but it does not appear to have access to the rest of the `my_object` instance. My assumption is that multiprocess is only pickling the `test` method and not the rest of the object instance. Is that correct? If not, why does the second method work, but not the first one?

Edit: Included `my_object` code body

Comment: You're missing the part that shows the consumption of your queue, i.e., the thread that the constructor starts. Please show a complete reproducible example

Comment: @MadPhysicist done

Comment: Do you understand what get_nowait does?

Comment: Yes. It attempts to read from the queue and throws a queue empty exception if there is nothing to read. Its a non-blocking call